# Place Order button not working in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Place Order button not working in WooCommerce and getting error in console

> ```
> touch-keyboard-navigation.js?ver=1.0:190 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of undefined
>     at removeAllFocusStates (touch-keyboard-navigation.js?ver=1.0:190)
>     at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (touch-keyboard-navigation.js?ver=1.0:321)
> ```

Comment: Whats the error you are getting?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of undefined
    at removeAllFocusStates (touch-keyboard-navigation.js?ver=1.0:190)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (touch-keyboard-navigation.js?ver=1.0:321)
removeAllFocusStates @ touch-keyboard-navigation.js?ver=1.0:190
(anonymous) @ touch-keyboard-navigation.js?ver=1.0:321

Comment: move all your script elements down in the DOM just before the body close tag

Comment: Did you ever resolve @VipulRai?